# Make fails to build simple Hello Pass in LLVM

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I have installed LLVM and Clang on Ubutnu 14.04 machine following this [tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/01/17/building-clang-libcpp-ubuntu-linux/). I can successfully compile and run the example given at the tutorial. Now when I try to build the simple `Hello Pass` given [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#introduction-what-is-a-pass), where it says to just run `gmake` in the directory, so I run `make` and get this:

```
../../../Makefile.common:60: ../../../Makefile.config: No such file or directory
../../../Makefile.common:68: /Makefile.rules: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/Makefile.rules'.  Stop.
```

Why is that? Is there a way I can build this Hello Pass?

Comment: See https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples for up-to-date working samples of building LLVM passes and other LLVM-and-Clang-using utilities.

Answer (score 1):

The autotools version of the build are being deprecated.

Use cmake to generate Unix makefiles in LLVM build directory do: cmake [llvm.src] -G"Unix Makefiles"

Comment: While the community may deprecate the autotools stuff anytime soon, still the problem here is that @user1343318 forgot to run configure.